# Which is my server?

Tags: c++, server, boost-asio

I compiled one simple example from library ASIO http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.11.0/src/examples/cpp03/allocation/server.cpp

and the instructions tell me to use "Usage: server < port > " but which is my server and port?

I used my ip and port from http://www.ipchicken.com/ but nothing.

Comment: `server` is the name of the program, and port number can be anything above `1024` and below `65535` that is not taken (you will get an error if you pick one that is taken).

Comment: You must present the questionable code _in the question_ on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a server; you're not connecting to one.

The program is called `server`. The one argument is the port on which the server shall listen.

Just choose a port.

```
server 12345
```

Next time actually *read* the accompanying article, rather than just copy/pasting the code without the faintest whiff of comprehension, then acting surprised when you don't know how to use it!

Comment: Very nice, but I have one little complicated "Usage: http_server <address> <port> <doc_root>", what should I use to <address> and <doc_root>?

Comment: @OanaAndone: Is there something preventing you from reading the text that goes along with this example program? That explains it? And that tells you how to use it? I'm confused as to why you are asking us to reproduce it all here.

Comment: Program give me this example "Usage: http_server <address> <port> <doc_root>" when I use in terminal ./http_server, but I do not know what should be address and doc_root.

Comment: Read some documentation. Perform some research!!